# Can't use Proxyman when connect "my computer as proxy server" to wifi hotspot from android phone or any organization wifi network. How to solve?

Tags: android, proxy, automated-tests, wifi, proxyman

I use an android phone to share hotspot wifi and I connect my macbook and iphone with that hotspot and use proxyman on my macbook as proxy server then set proxy setting on iphone like it said in proxyman configuration manual but after that, the iphone can't go to any page or even connect to the internet. How to solve this?

I tried using iPhone to share wifi hotspot instead but it work properly. Macbook can represent itself as proxy server just right and the device connecting to this proxy can access to internet.
But anytime I use android phone to share hotspot, devices that connect to proxy server can't connect to internet. This happened with my organization network wifi too.

Helpp! I need to test the app on the iPhone but I don't have another iPhone device left to share hotspot. Even the android phone can share hotspot, but the reason why it failed is like above.